# What would the relative velocity of the inertial systems in the image need to be in order for the S' observer to measure no net electromagnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I'm attempting to reteach myself that which I've forgotten during my physics studies. Currently looking at relativity.

**The set-up**

The observers in $S$ and $S'$ see identical electric fields $2k\lambda\over y_{1}$, at a distance $y_{1}=y_{1}'$ from an
infinitely long wire carrying uniform charge $\lambda$ per unit length. Observers in both $S$ and $S´$ measure
a force $2kq\lambda \over y_{1}$ on $q$ due to the line of charge; however, the $S'$ observer measures an add tional
force $-μ_{0}\lambda v^2 q \over 2 \pi y_{1}$ due to the magnetic field at $y_{1}'$ arising from the motion of the wire in the
$-x'$ direction.

[image]

**The Problem**: What would the relative velocity of the inertial systems in the image need to be in order for the `S'` observer to measure no net electromagnetic force on charge `q`?

**My solution**

Starting with
$$
F=qE + q\textbf v \times \textbf B = 0
$$
Using
$$
qE = {2k\lambda q\over y_{1}}
$$
And
$$
q\textbf v \times \textbf B = {\mu_{0}v^2 q \lambda \over 2 \pi y_{1}}
$$
I simplified to
$$
0 = {2k\lambda q\over y_{1}} + {\mu_{0}v^2 q \lambda \over 2 \pi y_{1}}
$$
Then
$$
v = \sqrt{4 \pi y_{1}k \over \mu_{0}}
$$

**My Questions**

1. Is this solution of any significance? Or, more simply put, is this velocity "special"? I feel like I've seen this expression before elsewhere, but searching directly for it hasn't yielded any results.
2. Did I do all the math correctly?

Comment: Your magnetic term should come with a minus sign as is written in the text. The text is horribly wrong in the physics. SR says that the E field will be transformed and not the same numerical value between the two frames, and the observer in $S^\prime$ is not moving, and will thus never feel any magnetic force. If you want the derivation to make any physical sense, you need to consider a physically sensible version of this problem.